# Best practice for validating correct format of elements in list of dicts

Tags: python, validation, try-catch

I have a list of dicts containing data sourced from an API, and want to iterate over this list, and verify that the data for each key is in the correct formatting. I have separate functions which achieve this, however I want to integrate these into one overall function.

e.g. from this:

```
validate_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%d-%m-%Y')
validate_name = isinstance(name, str)
```

To something like this:

```
def validate_content(row):
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0], '%d-%m-%Y')
    except:
        raise ValueError('Incorrect date format detected')

    try:
        isinstance(row[1], str)
    except:
        raise ValueError('Incorrect name format detected')
```

Obviously this syntax isn't correct, could someone inform me of the best solution to validating multiple fields like this?

sample data (index 4 and 5 should throw errors):

```
names_and_dates = [{'date': '10-10-2018', 'name': 'Monday'},
                   {'date': '11-10-2018', 'name': 'Tuesday'},
                   {'date': '12-10-2018', 'name': 'Wednesday'},
                   {'date': '13-10-2018', 'name': 'Thursday'},
                   {'date': '2018-10-14', 'name': 'Friday'},
                   {'date': '15-10-2018', 'name': 55}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just some minior modifications:

```
from datetime import datetime

def validate_content(row):
    try:
        datetime.strptime(row['date'], '%d-%m-%Y')
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError('Incorrect date format detected')

    if not isinstance(row['name'], str):
        raise ValueError('Incorrect name format detected')
```

1. not a plain `except` but an `except ValueError` (this will not catch the exception raised if the dictionary does not contain a `'date'` key; that should probably be handled elsewhere)
2. `isinstance` just returns `False` but does not raise an error if the instance is not a `str`; surrounding it with `try/except` will not have the effect you want.

this in action:

```
names_and_dates = [{'date': '10-10-2018', 'name': 'Monday'},
                   {'date': '11-10-2018', 'name': 'Tuesday'},
                   {'date': '12-10-2018', 'name': 'Wednesday'},
                   {'date': '13-10-2018', 'name': 'Thursday'},
                   {'date': '2018-10-14', 'name': 'Friday'},
                   {'date': '15-10-2018', 'name': 55}]

for row in names_and_dates:
    try:
        validate_content(row)
        print('valid row {}'.format(row))
    except ValueError as e:
        print('invalid row {}\n  exception: {}'.format(row, e))
```

will output:

```
valid row {'date': '10-10-2018', 'name': 'Monday'}
valid row {'date': '11-10-2018', 'name': 'Tuesday'}
valid row {'date': '12-10-2018', 'name': 'Wednesday'}
valid row {'date': '13-10-2018', 'name': 'Thursday'}
invalid row {'date': '2018-10-14', 'name': 'Friday'}
  exception: Incorrect date format detected
invalid row {'date': '15-10-2018', 'name': 55}
  exception: Incorrect name format detected
```

Comment: Thankyou, is the second try statement only replaced because of the isinstance method? e.g. if I added another function to check the format of a time key, would that need to be try or if?

Comment: that depends whether your check function returns `True/False` (no exception handling needed) or fails with an exception (e.g. `int(x)` will fail raise a `ValueError` for `x='a'`); then you need a `try/except` block.

Comment: Great, thanks for all the help that's cleared things up.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there:

```
import datetime

def validate_content(row):
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(row["date"], '%d-%m-%Y')
    except:
        raise ValueError('Incorrect date format detected: {}'.format( row["date"] ))

    if not  isinstance(row["name"], str):
        raise ValueError('Incorrect name format detected: {}'.format( row["name"] ))


names_and_dates = [{'date': '10-10-2018', 'name': 'Monday'},
                   {'date': '11-10-2018', 'name': 'Tuesday'},
                   {'date': 'Hello world', 'name': 'Tuesday'},
                   {'date': '12-12-2020', 'name': 55},
                   ]

for index, item in enumerate(names_and_dates):
    try:
        validate_content(item)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error in item {}: {}".format(index, e))
```

Output:

```
Error in item 2: Incorrect date format detected: Hello world
Error in item 3: Incorrect name format detected: 55
```

Comment: So all that's involved is replacing the second try statement with an if function?